# How do I POST data from an asp.net MVC controller to a non-MVC asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, post, get

One department in our company is using classic asp.net while ours department is using MVC.

We need to pass 5 variables to his page (by form submit). Can someone please show a simple example of posting form data from an MVC controller to an asp.net page expecting the form variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, you should be able to do this without any cross domain / application concern. You want to do this in the controller, so you can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=VS.80).aspx) class to post the data. It's conceptually the same as posting from a web browser as far as the target application is concerned.

Here's a quick and dirty snippet:

```
// name / value pairs. field names should match form elements
string data = field2Name + "=" + field1Value + "&" + field2Name+ "=" + field2Value

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(<url to other applications form action>);

// set post headers
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// write the data to the request stream         
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(data);

// iirc this actually triggers the post
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I'm looking for. Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: remember to flush your writer or use 
   using(var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
   {
       writer.Write(data);
   }

Answer (score 0):

If you are crossing domains, or applications, I think you might be out of luck.  Can you direct to the other site and use the querystring?

Or write to a table and direct to the other site.

Really not sure you'll be able to post to the other site as I think it goes against the security model.

Comment: I can't use query string because of security exposure, and it's too easy for users to modify. It is crossing domains.

Comment: For crossing domain, convert your object to JSON and Serialize Javascript, then assign it to ViewBag if the controller returns the View or TempData if it redirects to another View. Then this is what I did: use AngularJS to post to a WebAPI with CORS enabled. WebAPI can specify URLs that are permitted to post to its controller. The @Html.Raw(TempData["yourdata"]) can be assigned to a Javascript object where Angular can post it to the WebAPI. Refer to this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32769992/1171842 . For Classic ASP, the code that accepts data need to be ported to WebAPI.

Answer (score -1):

I might be missing the subtle problem, but can't you just set the `action` on the MVC form to the url of the classic asp page that will receive it?

The fields will be available in the form headers which you can read on the ASP side.

The only issue will be if the ASP site has cross site request forgery detection (but if they're inhouse apps, you can add an exception to the forgery detection code on the ASP side).